# How to calculate Training and testing accuracy in image classification using SVM in matlab

Tags: matlab, svm

I am trying to classify the four groups of images using `SVM` method, by randomly selecting training and testing data each time. When T run the program the performance varies due to randomly selecting data. How to get accurate performance of my algorithm and also how to calculate training and testing accuracy?

The formula I am using for performance is

```
Performance = sum(PredictedLabels == test_labels) / numel(PredictedLabels)
```

I am using `multisvm` function for classification.

Comment: This is a better measure of performance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

Actually the performance measure is acceptable, though there are some other slightly better choices like @Dan has mentioned.

More importantly, you need to deal with randomness.

1) Everytime you select your `training` data, test the `trained` model with multiple randomized `test` data and average the accuracy. (e.g. 10 times or so)

2) Use multiple `trained` model and average the performance to get general performance.

Remark:

1) You need to make sure the `training` data and `test` data do not overlap. Or it is no longer `test` data.

2) It is better to have the `training` data have the same number of samples from each `class label`. This means you can partition your dataset in advance.